# SQL - Displaying records from a table where the foreign key value matches the primary key value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

My title may not adequately explain my question, so please feel free to edit it if necessary.

I am creating a project where a user makes bookings for guest houses using HTML and PHP pages to access the database.

I have made a page that asks the user what city they want to stay in, and displays the names of all the guest houses in the city that they choose. (`Name` being just a plain column, no primary key)
Then, I want to ask them which of those guest houses they want to stay in, and display the rooms for that guest house.

However, I am not sure what query I need to write to do so.

The `rooms` table has a foreign key `GuestHouseID_FK` that links to the primary key `GuestHouseID` (auto-incremented) in the `guest_house` table. So each room in a particular guest house will have the same ID number.

So my question is, can I write a query that displays all the rooms from the `Rooms` table WHERE the `GuestHouseID_FK` value matches the `GuestHouseID` value of the guest house name they chose?

Here's the SQL so you can see the names:

```
CREATE TABLE Guest_House (
GuestHouseID int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
City varchar(30) NOT NULL,
NumOfRooms int(2) NOT NULL,
Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Rating char(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Rooms (
Room_Number int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NumOfBeds int(2) NOT NULL,
Ensuite char(1) NOT NULL,
Room_Service char(1) NOT NULL,
CostPerDay double(10, 2) NOT NULL,
GuestHouseID_FK int(4) NOT NULL,

INDEX GuestHouseID_FK (GuestHouseID_FK),

CONSTRAINT rooms_guest_house FOREIGN KEY (GuestHouseID_FK) REFERENCES Guest_House (GuestHouseID)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

As always, I appreciate your answers, and I apologize if this is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query.

```
select Rooms.* from Rooms 
Left Join Guest_House ON (Guest_House.GuestHouseID = Rooms.GuestHouseID_FK)
where Guest_House.GuestHouseID = "your id" ;
```